# org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Send failed; Topic dpp_cil.dpp.event.external.downstream_response not present in metadata after 60000 ms

Tags: java, integration-testing, spring-kafka, spring-kafka-test, embedded-kafka

Integration test for ProducerServiceIntegrationTest is giving error : org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Send failed; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic dpp_cil.dpp.event.external.downstream_response not present in metadata after 60000 ms.

Though  testTopicCreation() is green and itShould_ProduceCorrectExampleDTO_to_TOPIC_EXAMPLE_EXTERNE() is giving the above error. Why? How to fix it.

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.SendResult;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture;

import java.util.Objects;



@Service
public class DownstreamActionResponseProducer{
    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DownstreamActionResponseProducer.class);
private String topicName = "dpp_cil.dpp.event.external.downstream_response";

private  KafkaTemplate<String, DownstreamActionResponse> kafkaTemplate;

    DownstreamActionResponseProducer(KafkaTemplate kafkaTemplate) {
        this.kafkaTemplate = kafkaTemplate;
    }
  public void send(DownstreamActionResponse event) {

log.info("Send event to the {} topic, {}",event,topicName);
      ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, DownstreamActionResponse>> future = kafkaTemplate.send(topicName,getKey(event), event);
      try {
      SendResult<String, DownstreamActionResponse> sendResult = future.get();
      log.info("Producer OUTPUT:\nMetadata:{}", sendResult.getRecordMetadata());
      log.info("Message sent by producer is:{} at offset:{} ",sendResult.getProducerRecord().value(),sendResult.getRecordMetadata().offset() );
    } catch (final InterruptedException ex) {
      Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
      log.warn("Kafka producer interrupted exception", ex);
    } catch (final Exception ex) {
      log.warn("Kafka producer exception", ex);
    }
  }

  private String getKey(DownstreamActionResponse event) {
    return Objects.toString(event.getAcid());
  }

}
```

```
import io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.EnableKafka;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ProducerFactory;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaProducerConfiguration {
    @Value("${spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap.servers}")
    private String bootstrapServers;
    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, DownstreamActionResponse> producerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroSerializer.class);
        configProps.put("schema.registry.url","http://localhost:8081"); 
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, DownstreamActionResponse> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }
}
```

```
server:
  port: 28081 # Can clash with local schema registry

spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      bootstrap.servers: localhost:29092
      schema.registry.url: http://localhost:8081
      security: false
    producer:
      topics:
        external.downstream_response: dpp_cil.dpp.event.external.downstream_response
      auto.register.schemas: true
      bootstrap.servers: localhost:29092
      schema.registry.url: http://localhost:8081
```

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClient;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.NewTopic;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.Consumer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer;
import org.springframework.kafka.test.EmbeddedKafkaBroker;
import org.springframework.kafka.test.context.EmbeddedKafka;
import org.springframework.kafka.test.utils.KafkaTestUtils;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.DirtiesContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {DownstreamActionResponseProducer.class, KafkaProducerConfiguration.class})  
@DirtiesContext
@EmbeddedKafka(topics = {"dpp_cil.dpp.event.external.downstream_response"})
@ActiveProfiles("local")

public class ProducerServiceIntegrationTest {
    private static final String TOPIC_EXAMPLE_EXTERNE = "dpp_cil.dpp.event.external.downstream_response";

    @Autowired
    private EmbeddedKafkaBroker embeddedKafkaBroker;

    @Autowired
    private DownstreamActionResponseProducer downstreamActionResponseProducer;


    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        // Check if the topic exists; if not, create it
        try (AdminClient adminClient = AdminClient.create(Map.of(
                AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, embeddedKafkaBroker.getBrokersAsString()
        ))) {
            if (!adminClient.listTopics().names().get().contains(TOPIC_EXAMPLE_EXTERNE)) {
                NewTopic newTopic = new NewTopic(TOPIC_EXAMPLE_EXTERNE, 1, (short) 1);
                adminClient.createTopics(Collections.singleton(newTopic)).all().get();
            }
        }
    }
    @Test
    public void testTopicCreation() {
        try (AdminClient adminClient = AdminClient.create(Map.of(
                AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, embeddedKafkaBroker.getBrokersAsString()
        ))) {
            assertTrue(adminClient.listTopics().names().get().contains(TOPIC_EXAMPLE_EXTERNE));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error testing topic creation", e);
        }
    }

    public DownstreamActionResponse mockExampleDTO(String name, String description) {
        DownstreamActionResponse exampleDTO = new DownstreamActionResponse();
        exampleDTO.setAcid(description);
        exampleDTO.setBrand(name);
        return exampleDTO;
    }
    /**
     * We verify the output in the topic. With an simulated consumer.
     */
    @Test
    public void itShould_ProduceCorrectExampleDTO_to_TOPIC_EXAMPLE_EXTERNE() {
        // GIVEN
        DownstreamActionResponse exampleDTO = mockExampleDTO("Un nom", "Une description");
        // simulation consumer
        Map<String, Object> consumerProps = KafkaTestUtils.consumerProps("group_consumer_test", "false", embeddedKafkaBroker);
        consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        Deserializer<DownstreamActionResponse> avroDeserializer = new ErrorHandlingDeserializer<DownstreamActionResponse>();
        ConsumerFactory<String, DownstreamActionResponse> cf = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerProps,
                new StringDeserializer(), avroDeserializer);
         Consumer<String, DownstreamActionResponse> consumerServiceTest = cf.createConsumer();

        embeddedKafkaBroker.consumeFromAnEmbeddedTopic(consumerServiceTest, TOPIC_EXAMPLE_EXTERNE);
        // WHEN
        downstreamActionResponseProducer.send(exampleDTO);
        // THEN
        ConsumerRecord<String, DownstreamActionResponse> consumerRecordOfExampleDTO = KafkaTestUtils.getSingleRecord(consumerServiceTest, TOPIC_EXAMPLE_EXTERNE);
       DownstreamActionResponse valueReceived = consumerRecordOfExampleDTO.value();

        assertEquals("Une description", valueReceived.getAcid());
        assertEquals("Un nom", valueReceived.getBrand());

        consumerServiceTest.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such property `...producer.topics`.

If you want the framework to provision the topic for you (for production code), you must add a `NewTopic` `@Bean` - see https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#configuring-topics

For test code, the topics are provisioned via the embedded broker annotation.

However, your configuration is wrong; use `bootstrap-servers` in that context, not `bootstrap.servers`. Also, it's best to set it at the top level if its the same for both the producer and consumer `spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers`.

But, in any case, your test embedded kafka broker will be listening on a random port; you need to tell Boot what that port is, so...

```java
@EmbeddedKafka(topics = "someTopic",
        bootstrapServersProperty = "spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers") // this is now the default (since 3.0.10).
```